# passing arrays as an argument to a function

Tags: c++

in the following code i want to enter some records thorugh array and finally want to compare the records of string to generate an output. not getting the funcationality of compare function. please help...................

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int compare(string record[20], int numb1)
{
    system("pause");
    int i;
    string str, substring;
    cout<<"enter the string"<<endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    for (i=0;i<numb1;i++)
    {
        if(str == record[i])
        {
               substring = str.substr(0,2); 
        }
        break;
    }
    if (substring == 'del')
    {
             cout<<"you have a delux type"<<endl;
    }
    else if ('bas' == substring)
    {
         cout<<"you have a basics type"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"invalid id"<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int enter_record(int n)
{
    int i;
    string rec[20];
    char choice_1;
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
    cout<<"enter value for "<<i+1<<" record"<<endl;
    cin>> rec[i];
    }
    cout <<"\t\t\t FINAL DESIGNED PACKAGES ARE :- "<<endl;
    cout <<"\t\t\t ----------------------------"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
              cout<<i+1<<". "<<rec[i]<<endl;
    }         
    cout<< "\t\t\tdo you want to compare an string (y/n)"<<endl;
    if ('y' == choice_1)
    {
       compare(rec, n);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int numb;
    cout<<"\t\t\t WELCOME TO TOUR PACKAGE CHECKING"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t --------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"enter number of records you want"<<endl;
    cin>>numb;
    enter_record(numb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` (the latter in this case, as you input the size you need). They make your life a lot easier. Also, prefer algorithms such as `std::find` to your own, and make sure you compare against *strings*.

Comment: Please get rid of the [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html). I almost ran your code on my system to test it, and on my system the `pause` command pauses the cooling system on my home nuclear reactor.

Comment: i think pause is an alternative if getch();

Comment: @user1938089: Maybe on your machine. But you have no idea whether my machine has a command called "pause" or, if so, what it does. If you're trying to write C++ code, you should do that.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, single ticks are used for characters. `del` is not a legal character. So you want `"del"`, not `'del'`. But really, you should use something smarter than a C-style array.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `substring = str.substr(0,3);` instead of `str.substr(0,2);`. Remember the **2nd parameter is length of substring**. So if you use `2`, instead of `del`, you would get `de`. This is why, I am guessing, you are getting **"invalid id"** all the time. You also need to fix the quotes around the strings as @David says.

There are other problems with your code of course, like buffer overflow.. You assume a max of 20 records, but I could try to enter 200... Take @chris's advice and use `std::vector` instead of a raw array of strings.

---

### Edit

Before you get to the above mentioned issues, you have a logical error as well. See the below snippet.

```
cout<< "\t\t\tdo you want to compare an string (y/n)"<<endl;
if ('y' == choice_1)
{
   compare(rec, n);
}
```

You ask the user for input and yet **you dont actually input it**. Thus you are comparing an uninitialized `char` against `y` which is likely false, thus the compare function is never called.

You should add a `cin>>choice_1` before the `if`.

Comment: the control is not able to call the compare function

Comment: @user1938089 ofcourse.. you dont `cin>>choice_1`!!!

Comment: yup i did it, but in compare function it is only executing the else condition only. i used cin instead of getline in line number 12, 13

Comment: @user1938089 please read my entire answer, the first part predicts the `else` only issue.

Comment: @user1938089 point to be noted, its typically not a good idea to mix getline and cin.

Comment: if((compare.record[i], str) == 0)

Comment: wats the error in this line??

Comment: @user1938089 It is different from the code you put up.. but id say that compare function probably still returns 0 for every case?